# if $\vec{x},\vec{y} \in \Bbb{R^4}$ with $\vec{x},\vec{y}$ being linearly independent prove that there exists a $\vec{a}$ that is orthogonal to both?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, orthogonality

let $\vec{x},\vec{y} \in \Bbb{R^4}$ with $\vec{x},\vec{y}$ being linearly independent how would you prove that there exists a non-zero vector $\vec{a}$ that is orthogonal to both?

I know that since its linearly independent the only solution to 
$c_1\vec{x}+c_2\vec{y}=0$ is when $c_1=c_2=0$ and that $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{x}=0$, $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{y}=0$ but im stuck on how to use all this to reach the conclusio

Answer (score 2):

Since $\vec x,\vec y$ are linearly independent, their span forms a $2$-dimensional plane in $\Bbb R^4$. Consider a normal vector to this plane.

Comment: that makes sense but is there anyway to show this normal vector since the cross product isnt defined in $\Bbb{R^4}$?

Comment: We don't need the cross product. The normal vector to an arbitrary two-dimensional plane $ax+by=c$ is...?

Comment: a vector orthogonal to every vector in the plane?

Comment: @amd yes you're right that is confusing, I meant "a".

Answer (score 1):

The null space of a matrix is the orthogonal complement of its row space, so you can take any vector in the null space of $\small\begin{bmatrix}\vec x & \vec y \end{bmatrix}$.